# AWS Xray-Daemon locally, unable to connect Xray using Xray-daemon from my app

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-xray

I'm running Xray daemon locally, and I wanted to push the data to Xray from my docker app by setting up daemon `AWSXRay.setDaemonAddress('127.0.0.1:2000')`.

Verified the daemon installation by running `cat segment.txt > /dev/udp/127.0.0.1/2000` inside the daemon container and its working well, how to run this outside of the container?

```
2020-05-11T04:39:45Z [Debug] processor: sending partial batch
2020-05-11T04:39:45Z [Debug] processor: segment batch size: 1. capacity: 50
2020-05-11T04:39:46Z [Info] Successfully sent batch of 1 segments (1.653 seconds)
2020-05-11T04:40:19Z [Debug] Send 1 telemetry record(s)
```

Created a new network as Mynetwork and connected both the containers (app and daemon) to that. Even able to ping them

```
docker exec -ti Myapp ping daemon
```

Tried passing IP address, docker ipv4 address (172.21.0.2), and name of the container as *xray-daemon* for host in AWSXRay.setDaemonAddress('host:2000') but nothing is happening neither an error nor any success in the daemon logs.

Can see the configured message in the app logs but it seems like the linking is not happening

```
2020-05-11 11:19:49.895 +00:00 [INFO] Configured daemon address to 127.0.0.1:2000
```

Any suggestions to access daemon in my app?

Here are my application logs, my app is a dockerized node application.

```
2020-05-12 02:48:33.359 +00:00 [DEBUG] Starting the AWS X-Ray SDK in automatic mode (default).
2020-05-12 02:48:33.364 +00:00 [DEBUG] AWS_XRAY_CONTEXT_MISSING is set. Configured context missing strategy to LOG_ERROR.
2020-05-12 02:48:33.389 +00:00 [INFO] Using custom sampling rules file: src/utils/awsXrayRule.json
2020-05-12 02:48:33.394 +00:00 [INFO] Configured daemon address to 127.0.0.1:2000.
app listening on port 3000!
2020-05-12 02:49:29.342 +00:00 [DEBUG] Starting segment: MY_NODE_APP
2020-05-12 02:49:29.352 +00:00 [DEBUG] Segment sent: {"trace_id:"1-5eba0eb9-8fda8d30ca36e717ae849f68","id":"a96cdf725443768e"}
2020-05-12 02:49:29.352 +00:00 [DEBUG] UDP message sent: {"trace_id":"1-5eba0eb9-8fda8d30ca36e717ae849f68","id":"a96cdf725443768e","start_time":1589251769.342,"name":"MY_NODE_APP","service":{"runtime":"node","runtime_version":"v13.10.1","version":"1.0.0","name":"my-node-app"},"aws":{"xray":{"sdk":"X-Ray for Node.js","sdk_version":"3.0.0","package":"aws-xray-sdk"}},"annotations":{"key1":"value2"},"end_time":1589251769.346}
```

samplingrules.json:

```
{
   "version": 1,
   "default": {
     "fixed_target": 1,
     "rate": 1.0
   }
 }
```

Comment: Your local X-ray daemon credentials are all correct so that it can access the X-ray service at AWS?

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind posting your application logs ? I think to debug this we need to make sure that your application running in one container is sending data (so that we can make sure application is instrumented properly) and if application is not sending data properly then you will see this (https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-xray-recorder-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/xray/emitters/UDPEmitter.java#L84) in your application logs.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67322314/430202), it could be failing to connect the daemon because the app running in the Docker container cannot connect to the X-Ray daemon running locally on the host.

You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67322314/430202) helpful. There is a simple Docker platform example that runs the daemon and the app side-by-side in separate containers. It uses docker-compose networking and the AWS_XRAY_DAEMON_ADDRESS environment variable to connect the app container to the daemon.