# api unable to send the traces to aws-xray deamon in docker container

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, docker, aws-xray

I have two docker containers for rest API and x-ray daemon up and running. In my local, API sends the traces to x-ray daemon successfully. But unable to achieve in docker.

These steps I have followed.

- added was x-ray filter to API to instrument HTTP request
- configured 0.0.0.0:2000 as x-ray deamon address to listen all request
- pulled AWS x-ray daemon official docker image and run the image in docker

whenever I am trying to hit my API,I am getting exception like this

```
2020-06-03 08:08:33.799  INFO 1 --- [pool-1-thread-1] c.a.x.s.sampling.pollers.RulePoller      : Polling sampling rules.2020-06-03 08:08:34.413 ERROR 1 --- [pool-1-thread-1] c.a.x.s.sampling.pollers.RulePoller      : Encountered error polling GetSamplingRules:
```

com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to 0.0.0.0:2000 [/0.0.0.0] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1207) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.787.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1153) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.787.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.787.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.787.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.787.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.787.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.787.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.787.jar!/:na]        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.787.jar!/:na]        at com.amazonaws.services.xray.AWSXRayClient.doInvoke(AWSXRayClient.java:1607) ~[aws-java-sdk-xray-1.11.787.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.services.xray.AWSXRayClient.invoke(AWSXRayClient.java:1574) ~[aws-java-sdk-xray-1.11.787.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.services.xray.AWSXRayClient.invoke(AWSXRayClient.java:1563) ~[aws-java-sdk-xray-1.11.787.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.services.xray.AWSXRayClient.executeGetSamplingRules(AWSXRayClient.java:800) ~[aws-java-sdk-xray-1.11.787.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.services.xray.AWSXRayClient.getSamplingRules(AWSXRayClient.java:771) ~[aws-java-sdk-xray-1.11.787.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.xray.strategy.sampling.pollers.RulePoller.pollRule(RulePoller.java:65) ~[aws-xray-recorder-sdk-core-2.4.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.xray.strategy.sampling.pollers.RulePoller.lambda$start$0(RulePoller.java:46) ~[aws-xray-recorder-sdk-core-2.4.0.jar!/:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 0.0.0.0:2000 [/0.0.0.0] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156) ~[httpclient-4.5.10.jar!/:4.5.10]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374) ~[httpclient-4.5.10.jar!/:4.5.10]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.787.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy64.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393) ~[httpclient-4.5.10.jar!/:4.5.10]
10]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186) ~[httpclient-4.5.10.jar!/:4.5.10]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.10.jar!/:4.5.10]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.10.jar!/:4.5.10]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.10.jar!/:4.5.10]
        at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.787.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1330) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.787.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.787.jar!/:na]
        ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:204) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75) ~[httpclient-4.5.10.jar!/:4.5.10]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142) ~[httpclient-4.5.10.jar!/:4.5.10]
        ... 37 common frames omitted

Comment: Did you resolve this issue. Stuck with the same issue and it would be great to help me.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with this solution:

1. start the X-Ray container
2. `docker inspect` on this container and check which is the IP address
3. Create an environment variable `AWS_XRAY_DAEMON_ADDRESS` with the value obtained in previous step (ex: 172.XX.0.X:2000)
4. start the application container adding `-e AWS_XRAY_DAEMON_ADDRESS` to pass the variable to the container (ex: `docker run -e AWS_XRAY_DAEMON_ADDRESS --name my_containter image_name`)

Steps 3 and 4 can be combined by directly passing the IP address to the container (`docker run -e AWS_XRAY_DAEMON_ADDRESS=ip_address --name my_containter image_name`)

Answer (score 0):

This could be because the app running in the Docker container cannot connect to the X-Ray daemon running locally on the host.

You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67287691/430202) helpful. There is a simple Docker platform example that runs the daemon and the app side-by-side in separate containers.  It uses docker-compose networking and the `AWS_XRAY_DAEMON_ADDRESS` environment variable to connect the app container to the daemon.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, starting containers in host network solves the issue (using `--network host` flag when starting container).
Other than that, the `AWS_XRAY_DAEMON_ADDRESS` environment variable can be used for setting XRay container IP address, as mentioned by @G. Ionut in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73944759/20156533).